# Grab screenshot of appended blob video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, blob, filereader

When saving a screenshot of large video files on a canvas, it seems that it cannot get its blob. It is working fine when the video blob has been displayed on the container.

Here's a [JSFiddle without timeout](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvpnppg3/) (does not work)

Here's a [JSFiddle with timeout](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvpnppg3/1/) (works)

```
$('#txtFileUpload').on('change', function() {
    var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
    for (var ctr = 0; ctr < countFiles; ctr++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        readerOnLoad(reader, ctr, $(this)[0], this.files[0]);
    }
});

var readerOnLoad = function(reader, ctr, fileInput, files) {
    reader.onloadend = (function(ctr) {
        return function(e, ctr) {
            var videoIdClass = 'thumb-video-' + ctr;
            var $video = $('<video />', {
                'src': e.target.result,
                'id': videoIdClass,
                'class': videoIdClass,
            }).appendTo($('.video-container')).wrap('<div class="thumb-container"></div>');
            setVideoCapture($video);
        };
    })(ctr);

    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[ctr]);
}

var setVideoCapture = function(videoElement) {
    var $output;
    var $canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var $img = document.createElement('img');

    $output = $('#output');
    $video = videoElement.get(0);

    $canvas.width = $video.videoWidth * 2;
    $canvas.height = $video.videoHeight * 2;
    $canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage($video, 0, 0, $canvas.width, $canvas.height);

    $img.src = $canvas.toDataURL();
    $output.prepend($img);
}
```

A quick fix would be set a timeout on the `setVideoCapture` method like this:

This works.

```
var setVideoCapture = function(videoElement) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $output;
        var $canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var $img = document.createElement('img');

        $output = $('#output');
        $video = videoElement.get(0);

        $canvas.width = $video.videoWidth * 2;
        $canvas.height = $video.videoHeight * 2;
        $canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage($video, 0, 0, $canvas.width, $canvas.height);

        $img.src = $canvas.toDataURL();
        $output.prepend($img);
    }, 2000, videoElement)
}
```

Weird that it has to be INSIDE the `setVideoCapture` method and not when triggering the `setVideoCapture` method like this:

This does not work.

```
reader.onloadend = (function(ctr) {
    return function(e, ctr) {
        var videoIdClass = 'thumb-video-' + ctr;
        var $video = $('<video />', {
            'src': e.target.result,
            'id': videoIdClass,
            'class': videoIdClass,
        }).appendTo($('.video-container')).wrap('<div class="thumb-container"></div>');
        setTimeout(setVideoCapture($video), 3000, $video);
    };
})(ctr);
```

But of course using a `setTimeout` is not a recommended fix. What should be is that `setVideoCapture` method should only be triggered when the `$video` element has already been appened and displayed on the container.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was able to fix this by:

```
$video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
   // do something here
}, false);
```